# Create a categorical variable (age categories) and apply to a table

Tags: r, categorical-data

I'm working with a large table with many variables, including "age".
Here is an example of what my table looks like:

1. Age  Var2   Var3   Var4    Var5
2. 32   John  Green  Married   6'1
3. 47   Julia Stone  Divorced  5'4
4. 72   Mike  White  Divorced  5'8

...

I am trying to add a variable to this table that classifies age in categories of 10 years, starting from 20 years old.

I have created my criterias:

```
mydata$age[mydata$age>=20 & mydata$age<=29] <- "20-29"
mydata$age[mydata$age>=30 & mydata$age<=39] <- "30-39"
mydata$age[mydata$age>=40 & mydata$age<=49] <- "40-49"
mydata$age[mydata$age>=50 & mydata$age<=59] <- "50-59"
mydata$age[mydata$age>=60 & mydata$age<=69] <- "60-69"
mydata$age[mydata$age>=70 & mydata$age<=79] <- "70-79"
```

Now, i want to add this as a variable in my table. So I want this variable to apply the right age category to every age listed in my data table. Here is an example of what it should look like:

1. Age  Var2   Var3   Var4    Var5  AgeClass
2. 32   John  Green  Married  6'1   30-39
3. 47   Julia Stone  Divorced 5'4   40-49
4. 72   Mike  White  Divorced 5'8   70-79
   ...

Anyone has an idea how to do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about the `cut` function, e.g.,

```
df = data.frame(Age=c(32,47,72), 
                Var2=c("John","Julia","Mike"), 
                Var3=c("Green","Stone","White"),
                Var4=c("Married","Divorced","Divorced"),
                Var5=c("6'1","5'4","5'8"))
df$age = cut(df$Age,breaks = seq(20,80,10), 
             labels=paste0(seq(20,70,10),"-",seq(30,80,10)-1))
```